# How to parse a month with DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a date input in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` to produce an output `YYYY-MM-DD` format , with PHP DateTime:

```
$input = '2015-12-07 19:01';
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m', $input);
echo $time->format('Y-m-d'); //outputs '2015-01-07'
```

But the output always shows month 01 (January), regardless of month input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`i` for minutes, not `m`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) ; Seems like time for a coffee ☕.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks - context switch from JavaScript moment.js to PHP DateTime threw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's `i` for minutes, not `m`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). So,

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $input);
```